# Does C++ Mutex guarantee avoiding race conditions?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am programming a simple example to test C++ Threads and Mutexes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

const int num_th = 50;
const int num_vals = 20;
const int num_it = 1000;

class MyVector {
 public:
  MyVector(int size): vals_(size, 0), idx_(0), mtx_() {}

  void inc() 
  {
    mtx_.lock();
    for(int i=0; i<num_it; i++)
    {
       vals_[idx_]++;
       idx_= (idx_+1) % num_vals;
    }
    mtx_.unlock();
  }

  int getVal(int idx) {return vals_[idx];}

private:
  std::mutex mtx_;
  int idx_;
  std::vector<int> vals_;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MyVector m(num_vals);

  std::thread t1[num_th];
  for(int i=0; i<num_th; i++)
     t1[i] = std::thread(&MyVector::inc, &m);

  for(int i=0; i<num_th;i++)
     t1[i].join();

  for(int i=0; i<num_vals; i++)
    std::cout<<" "<<m.getVal(i);

  return 0;
}
```

After execution, all the values should be the same, but this is the output:

```
 2053 2063 2054 2038 2029 2038 2036 2043 2048 2049 2048 2055 2055 2050 2050 2051 2051 2055 2042 2066
```

Does C++ Mutexes really guarantee mutual exclusion, or did I miss something?

Comment: why is race condition in the title

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/SLHM30043)

Comment: Your code has some issues (compile with warnings enabled to see) but none of them seems related to your problem.  I cannot find a data race and compiling with current GCC and Clang consistently produces all values 2500.  Using `-fsanitize=thread` also doesn't show any errors either.  My only guess is that you might have forgotten to tell your compiler to enable multi-threading (eg by passing the `-pthread` switch).  Please note that your direct using of `std::mutex` is not the recommended way; use `std::unique_lock` instead.

Comment: If you like `printf`-style debugging, add `std::cerr << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\t' << what << std::endl;` after / before you acquire / release the mutex where `what` is `"ENTER"` and `"EXIT"` respectively.

Comment: @5gon12eder For this one, `lock_guard` is slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

5gon12eder is right. With -pthread the problem is solved and the output is correct:

```
 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500 2500
```

I'm surprised you need to use the "-pthread" option to the compiler when using threads, and there are not compilation or linking errors.

PS: The compiler is gcc and the OS is Linux (g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4)